# Static methods vs instance method in testing java

Tags: java

Tengo una clase `SystemPropertyHelper` en la capa de servicios web, la cual tiene solo métodos estáticos para recuperar objetos del core de la aplicación, esto con el fin de no mezclar funcionalidades entre capas, y el manejo de las excepciones entre otras cosas.

El asunto es que estoy haciendo testing de la capa de servicios y necesito hacer mocking de este helper. Mi pregunta es, que implicaciones tendría hacer los métodos de esta clase helper no estáticos, es decir, que para usarlos tendría que crear instancias de la misma.

La razón que me lleva a hacerlo, es porque investigando recomienda en la medida de que la aplicación lo permita, refactorizar y convertir estos métodos estáticos en métodos de instancia, para no recurrir a librerías como PowerMock. Yo perfectamente lo puedo hacer, ya que esta fase de servicios esta comenzando, pero tengo esta duda, por un lado dicen que un método se debería hacer estático si este no guarda o modifica estado, que es de hecho mi caso, lo único que hace el `SystemPropertyHelper` es traerme el objeto y entregarlo a la capa de servicios, y por el otro lado recomiendan hacer los métodos no estáticos para una mejor aplicabilidad en el testing, espero entiendan el dilema. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El impacto que tiene de declarar una clase de utilidad depende en primer lugar de la pregunta si hay estados involucrados. Si todos los métodos de la clase utilitaria no necesitan contexto, no hay problema en remplazarlos con un servicio instado. Doy un Ejemplo simplificado:

**Caso 1 - clase sin estado**

```
public class Conv{

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public static String formatDato(Date d){
        return sdf.format(d);
    }

    public static Date dateDeString(String dato) throws ParseException {
        return sdf.parse(dato); 
    }
}

// uso
String fecha = Conv.formatDato(new Date());
```

Esta clase no tiene estado, entonces su uso se puede refacturar a:

```
public class Conv implements IConv{

    public static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public Conv(){};

    public String formatDato(Date d){
        return sdf.format(d);
    }

    public Date dateDeString(String dato) throws ParseException {
        return sdf.parse(dato); 
    }
}

// uso
String fecha = new Conv().formatDato(new Date());
```

Asumiendo que definimos la interfaz `IConv` con los métodos `formatDato` y `dateDeString` podemos crear un mock y intercambiar las clases.

**Caso 2 - clase con estado:**

imaginemos la misma clase de utilidad, pero con un método más que lo hace tener un estado:

```
public class Conv{

    private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public static String formatDato(Date d){
        return sdf.format(d);
    }

    public static Date dateDeString(String dato) throws ParseException {
        return sdf.parse(dato); 
    }

    // aquí existe la posibilidad que el formato y así el estado cambia
    public static void nuevoFormato(String formato)
              throws NullpointerException, IllegalArgumentException {
        sdf.applyPattern(format);
    }
}

// uso
String fecha = Conv.formatDato(new Date());
```

Porque la clase lleva un estado, no se te permite aplicar el mismo patron que en el otro ejemplo. En un mundo ideal te das cuenta que es muy poco recomendable de manejar estados en clases que proveen métodos estáticos.

**La solución recomendada**

Ya te diste cuenta como dos "mejores practicas" en el caso de "test driven development" causan problemas, entonces recuerda que no hay mejores practicas porque si, solamente hay malas y buenas estrategias para un contexto.

En tu caso una forma de acabar con todos los dolores de cabeza es seguir algunas simples reglas en el diseño:

- diseñemos todos los servicios como interfaz.
- implementamos los servicios según contexto (test, debug, release)
- creamos un `Context` que tiene métodos para obtener los servicios.
- en vez de usar utilidades estáticos entregamos clases de utilidad como **singleton**

El `Context`por ejemplo se podría ver así:

```
public class Context {

    public static final int TEST = 0;
    public static final int DEBUG = 1;
    public static final int RELEASE = 2;
    private static Context testContext = null;
    private static Context debugContext = null;
    private static Context releaseContext = null;
    private IDataBaseService dataBaseService=null;
    private IFileService fileService=null;
    private ITcpService tcpService=null;

    private int build=0;

    // método fabrica para obtener el contexto para el build
    // un singleton a demanda.
    public static Context getContext(Integer build){
        switch(build){

        case TEST:
            return (null==testContext) ? testContext = new Context(TEST) : testContext;
        case DEBUG:
            return (null==debugContext) ? debugContext = new Context(DEBUG) : debugContext;
        case RELEASE:   
        default:    
            return (null==releaseContext) ? releaseContext = new Context(RELEASE) : releaseContext;

        }
    }

    // los métodos de instancia de contexto también pueden entregar singleton según necesidad
    private Context(int build){ this.build = build; } 

    public IFileService getFileService(){
        if (null==fileService){
            switch(build){

            case TEST:
                FileService = new MockFileService();
            case DEBUG:
                fileService = new DebugFileService();
            case RELEASE:   
            default:    
                fileService = new FileService();

            }
        }
        return dataBaseService;
    }

    // ....
}
```

Con este diseño podemos crear y obtener el contexto que corresponde en cualquier variante de build con por ejemplo `Context context=Context.getContext(Context.TEST);` y luego los servicios simplemente con `IFileService fs = context.getFileService()` para el contexto adecuado.